# Project/versioning software - what's most commonly used for mobile/android?

Tags: android

Just curious whether folks still use CVS or if there are other versioning programs out there these days.  Been out of software development for a few years and just kind of have the itch to play around a bit with some mobile development.  I'd like something that I can share with at least one other remotely-located developer.  Is there an industry standard or a particular program that most folks doing android development use?

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 3):

CVS?  Ancient history.  It's either Subversion or Git these days.  The type of development seems immaterial to where you archive it.

Comment: Hah!  Thanks.  I was telling a story about writing a girl a letter the other day.   Probably back about the same time when I was using CVS :)

Answer (score 2):

I use Mercurial (hg) DVCS to manage my projects (not just for Java, but also C and Python).

IMHO Mercurial is quite a modern VCS with very good support for merging (it has to since it is a DVCS).

If you are going to be working in parallel and doing lots of merges I'd recommend [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to contribute to Android, you want to use git.  Google has a layer on top of it called repo, which does a good job of dealing with the problem space they are dealing with.

If your last exposure was CVS, however, you may find that git is so much more powerful that it becomes confusing.  hg is very good alternative.  If you have a project which you are sure will never branch, and you need it to be PHB friendly, I recommend SVN.